# How do i test for 404 errors in PHPUnit using Selenium Server

Tags: php, magento, selenium, phpunit

I'm trying to write tests with PHP Unit using Selenieum Server, one test i got to make is checking for 404 error pages for images and hyperlinks

the hard part to this is that the tests are for a Magento Setup so they have a custom 404 error page which is actually a CMS page but is selected in the backend to appear when you get a 404 error, also, my local server environment when i view an image which would 404 just shows a white page, in the same browser on a different server environment owned by a team mate, they have text showing up say "Bad Request", both URLS are the same and we entered the page in the exact same way

when i try using `$this->open('kjdasfhkfajdhkfjhafds')` which goes to a 404 error page it doesn't seem to throw an exception, i could check for elements on the page to see if they match the expected 404 page i would get but as i have said above, viewing an image gives a different page and that page is also different between servers

Answer (score 0):

I'm in exactly the same situation and I'm experimenting to find a solution. So far the one that seems to work is check.

```
$this->check($url);
```

seems to atleast return an error on 404 so I am going with that at the moment. If anybody has any better suggestions feel free to share them :-)